# Can't get access from the one class to the instance of another class

Tags: .net, visual-studio, c++-cli

**main.cpp**

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include <iostream>
 #include "Form1.h"
 #include "myclass.h"
using namespace Akva;

[STAThreadAttribute]
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{

Application::EnableVisualStyles();
Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 
Form1^ MainForm = gcnew Form1();
Application::Run(MainForm);
return 0;
};
```

**Form1.h**

```
#include "myclass.h"
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
        ...
    };
```

**myclass.h**

```
#include "Form1.h"
class MyClass
{
    public: void addBox();
};

void MyClass::addBox()
{
    PaintBox^ pb = cgnew PaintBox();
    MainForm->Controls->Add(pb);  //here
};
```

I can't get access from class "MyClass" to the instance "MainForm" in main.cpp.
How i can get it?

**UPD**: The code in myclass.h includes before i create the instance MainForm and instance of Form1 isn't visible in myclass.h.

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include <iostream>
 #include "Form1.h"
 #include "myclass.h"
using namespace Akva;

[STAThreadAttribute]
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{

Application::EnableVisualStyles();
Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 
Application::Run(gcnew Form1()); //here
return 0;
};
```

Another question: how i can get access to elements and instance of Form1?

I want to create PictureBox from "MyClass".

Comment: Your myclass.h header file #includes Form1.h.  Your Form1.h header file #includes myclass.h.  Circular dependencies like that cannot work.  You'll have to restructure your code so this cannot happen.  Which usually involves moving the implementation of some methods from Form1.h into a .cpp file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't get access from class "MyClass" to the instance "MainForm" in main.cpp. How i can get it?

`MainForm` is a local variable inside the method `main`. No code outside that method will ever be able to read that local variable.

You can pass the instance contained in the `MainForm` local variable to other code, so that the other code can access it, but there's not enough code shown to help you with that.

The way that you're trying to access `MainForm` in `MyClass::addBox` is like a global variable. Is that what you're trying to do? Global variables are generally to be avoided, but if that's what you want, declare it in a header file that both `main.cpp` and `myclass.cpp` can see, and initialize it like you're doing already in `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

> How i can get it?

You need to `#include myclass.h` in main.cpp  in order to use it within `Form1`.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two solutions:

- pass the form instance to the **MyClass constructor**:

  ```
  #include "Form1.h"

  class MyClass
  {
      private: MainForm^ mainForm;
      public: MyClass(MainForm^ mainForm);
      public: void addBox();
  };

  void MyClass::MyClass(MainForm^ mainForm)
  {
      this->mainForm = mainForm;
  }

  void MyClass::addBox()
  {
      PaintBox^ pb = cgnew PaintBox();
      mainForm->Controls->Add(pb);  //here
  };
  ```
- pass the form instance to the **addBox** method:

  ```
  #include "Form1.h"

  class MyClass
  {
      public: void addBox(MainForm^ mainForm);
  };

  void MyClass::MyClass(MainForm^ mainForm)
  {
      this->mainForm = mainForm;
  }

  void MyClass::addBox(MainForm^ mainForm)
  {
      PaintBox^ pb = cgnew PaintBox();
      mainForm->Controls->Add(pb);  //here
  };
  ```